# How Can I Disable ssl certificate Spring RestTemplate?

Tags: spring, ssl-certificate, resttemplate

In my Spring boot project I am trying to intercept the following POST call "https: // localhost: 8080" but I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name
```

I already know that to solve the problem it would be enough to change from https to http. But I don't want this.
I want my code to be able to automatically handle this situation.

In any case if I try to reach

This is the configuration of my RestTemplate in the App class:

How could I go about solving the problem ??

This is the configuration of my RestTemplate in the App class:

```
@EnableFeignClients
@ServletComponentScan
@Import(EmbeddedTomcatConfiguration.class)
// uncomment to enable auditor
//@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "auditorAware")
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {

        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
                HttpClientBuilder.create().build());
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory);
        return restTemplate;
    }

    @Autowired(required = true)
    public void configureJackson(ObjectMapper jackson2ObjectMapper) {
        // jackson2ObjectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        jackson2ObjectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        jackson2ObjectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> filterRegistrationBean() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        final CorsConfiguration config = buildCorsConfiguration();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        final FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }

    private CorsConfiguration buildCorsConfiguration() {
        final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);

        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        config.addExposedHeader(HttpHeaders.LOCATION);
        return config;
    }
}
```

How could I go about solving the problem ??

Comment: Does this article  (https://progressivecoder.com/avoid-ssl-validation-spring-boot-resttemplate/#:~:text=To%20skip%20or%20avoid%20the,with%20the%20normal%20Spring%20package.&text=In%20this%20configuration%20class%2C%20we,the%20certificate%20check%20as%20disabled) help?

Comment: I have already implemented a similar solution but have not gotten any results